# Rasterizing multiple objects separately

Tags: adobe-illustrator, raster

When combining graphic elements in an .ai file, these elements being large bitmap images (TIFF, PSD, PNG,...), I regularly use rasterize to reduce these images separately in size (and thus reducing file size) and thus make working with them a lot easier and faster.

However, when I try to rasterize multiple objects at once, these objects are always grouped in one big rasterized object.  Is there a way they remain separate objects?

Comment: Hi, are you asking how to scale multiple rasterized elements or are you asking how to rasterize multiple objects separately? Your title is asking a different question than what you wrote. Because a bitmap image is already rasterized.

Comment: Welcome to **GDSE** - please take a look around [tour] to learn about our community; please also carefully read [ask] and [answer] a question to understand what makes a good question, how to frame it for best responses, and what to expect from answers. As initially written, this question is pretty unclear, and therefore likely to get closed due to lack of clarity. Can you edit and refine it to be clearer? Bitmap images are already rasters - what exactly are you needing to do and where is it failing? Screencaps might help.

Comment: Why not just *link* the file sinto your doc? This would mostly eliminate any file size changes and massively reduce work time.

Comment: Well, because the source files can be really huge for one. Also I'm working with people who have a different operating system, so the links get messed up.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to rasterize a selection of objects seperately:

- Select all objects/groups you want to rasterize.
- Use *Effects > Rasterize...* to apply rasterization as an effect on each individual object.
- Use *Object > Expand Appearance* to convert the objects to images.

Comment: Thank you so much, that works like a charm!!

Comment: I'm glad to help. Please remember to *accept* the answer so others can benefit from it.